# Should I take my cat to the vet? Is it a wound or fungus?

Tags: cats, wound-care

I noticed like a week ago but I had to go out of town the same day so my sister was supposed to clean the wound and get her the cat come but couldn’t  do it
I just came back and it seems way bigger. Should I go to the vet ? [image]

Comment: Welcome to Pets! Please take the [tour], it only takes a minute. From the image it's not clear where on the cat this wound is located and how big it is. Could you please [edit] your question to add these details?

Answer (score 2):

I just showed it to my CVT wife and she says the cat should definitely go to the vet, particularly since it's not healing & getting worse. In the mean time, don't put bandages on it, but try to prevent the cat from licking/chewing there (you can get a cone at a pet store).